# Add bound IPs to /etc/network/interfaces, without network downtime

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

Setup is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS or Debian 7.

I can assign bound IPs to network interfaces without network downtime with ifconfig, but it doesn't persist across restarts (unless you use rc.local, which apparently isn't recommended), with:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:x <bound IP here>
```

What is the "preferred" way to do this that doesn't involve any network downtime (e.g. no ifup/ifdown)?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing.  you talk about no downtime and then about across reboots.    The majority of network setup can be done via the interfaces configuration file at /etc/network/interfaces. per the Debian documentation once you know what works from the ifconfig command you would then add it in to the interfaces file so that it is a permenant change. once added to interfaces the next reboot it should automatically kick in and unless you reboot your ifconfig changes should not go away.

Comment: So what you want to know is how to apply an updated `/etc/network/interfaces` file without using `service network restart`?

Answer (score 1):

do `sudo ifconfig eth0:x <bound IP here>` is quick way... but will not be there at reboot

or 
add this to your `/etc/network/interfaces` so settings will survive reboot or `service network restart`

```
auto eth0:x
iface eth0:x inet static
    address <bound IP here>
    # netmask 255.255.255.255
    # network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    # broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    # gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

and do `ifup eth0:x`

Comment: isn't that the answer you where looking for?